# Redirect to Python script in .htaccess while maintaining request URL

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, python, scriptalias

I have a website configured with Apache for `http://www.example.com` located in `/var/www/example.com/`. For an arbitrary sub-path of this website I would like to have all requests handled by a Python script. e.g. all requests for `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/` and below would be handled by `/var/www/example.com/foo/bar/index.py`.

One way to accomplish this is to use the `ScriptAlias` directive in the Apache config/virtual host, but I would like to accomplish this in the `.htaccess` file if possible as I'd rather not have to modify the Apache config every time I which to create a new directory with a Python script.

I have tried doing this using `mod_rewrite` as shown below, but this has problems in that the Python script thinks the request URL contains `/index.py/` which means that some URLs it generates for redirects are incorrect (this is causes problems such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271444/getting-flask-to-use-the-desired-url-behind-mod-rewrite)).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /foo/bar/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.py/$1 [L]
```

Is there another way to accomplish this or will I have to use `ScriptAlias`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible using purely `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` so it will either have to be done using `ScriptAlias` or [in the script itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692814/343486).